# Pegar numero depois da virgula

Tags: oracle, pl-sql

Trabalhando com plsql estou dividindo dois numeros, e gostaria de receber apenas o que vier depois da virgula. Ex: 7,89111. Preciso apenas do número 89111.

Comment: verifica se ajuda: https://community.oracle.com/thread/873045?start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caro,

A única forma que eu encontrei foi convertendo o número para String e fazendo um substring com ela.

Eu coloquei o valor com o ponto em vez de vírgula para fazer o teste, mas você pode colocar o seu campo nos dois valores que funciona bem.

```
select substr(to_char(7.89111), instr(to_char(7.89111), ',') + 1) from dual;
```

Resultado:

```
SUBST
-----
89111
```

Comment: Blz, isto mesmo. Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Eu faria assim, não tem necessidade de converter o valor para string, depois quando for executar um cálculo com o mesmo, vai ter que ficar convertendo novamente para number...

SELECT SUBSTR(7.89111, INSTR(7.89111, '.', 1, 1) + 1, 5) valor
  FROM dual;

Answer (score 1):

Se quiser pegar a parte decimal, faça isso:

```
SELECT 7.89111 - TRUNC(7.89111) from dual;
```

Resultado:0,89111

Se quiser pegar só os números depois da vírgula:

```
select REPLACE((7.89111 - trunc(7.89111)),',','') from dual;
```

Resultado: 89111

Answer (score 0):

Só subtrair o numero pela parte inteira do mesmo numero.

Depois se for necessário remover a virgula, basta extrair o texto apos a virgula;

```
select 7.8911 - trunc(7.8911) from dual; //resultado 0.8911

select substr(0.8911,2,length(0.8911)) from dual; //resultado 8911
```

Answer (score 0):

Você também pode utilizar a função MOD que retorna o resto da divisão, desta forma você realiza a divisão por 1 e tem o retorno.

SELECT MOD(7.89,1) FROM DUAL;
Resultado: 0.89

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).